# Why tabs content is visible always in materializecss

Tags: jquery, css, html, materialize

I was trying to test how can I create tabs using materialize, and I was testing this code

```
<div class="row"

<div class="col s12">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test1">Test 1 </a></li>
    <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test2">Test 2</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test3">Test 3</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="test1" class="col s12">Test 1</div>
<div id="test2" class="col s12">Test 2</div>
<div id="test3" class="col s12">Test 3</div>
<div id="test4" class="col s12">Test 4</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the content of all divs is always visible as shown in the following figure
[image]

I did intialize the tabs with this line $('ul.tabs').tabs();

Can you help me to know why am I getting this weird output? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you create a demo of the above issue? Is the missing `>` on `row` causing it?

Comment: can you create any fiddle or demo

Comment: @ManojKumar NO the error is not because of the missing > on row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was using jqueryUI in the same project , and this was causing conflict between the jQuery ui and materilizecss. The solution was to  build the jquery UI without tabs included. http://jqueryui.com/download/

Comment: In my case, the conflict was MaterializeCSS + Modernizr.

Comment: exactly, I had the conflict with jQueryUI too

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to the order in which your scripts are being loaded.

If you're using other libraries chances are that `$(document).ready(function() { ...` has been fired before everything else has been completely loaded, instead you should use:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
  ...
});
```

Also, bear in mind that if your scripts come from a cdn you should be checking for `async` and `defer` attributes.